# Custom Authentication in Alfresco Activiti

Tags: authentication, ldap, enterprise, activiti, business-process-management

How can I create my own custom authentication mechanism for Activiti.I have tried using LDAP provided in the activiti documentation here - https://docs.alfresco.com/activiti/docs/dev-guide/1.4.0/#_custom_identity_synchronization. but it's not what I want. I want a authentication mechanism of my own to co-op with Activiti.

I am using Activiti Enterprise version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: @Aditi don't judge or correct things what you don't know of. BTW it's Alfresco's tool "ACTIVITI", search it and get your facts right!

Comment: Ok.Thank you for clarification..
My mistake...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try override Activiti's security config. follow this https://docs.alfresco.com/activiti/docs/dev-guide/1.4.0/#_security_configuration_overrides

Comment: thanks. but can you provide a reference code or something?